# Reconstruct Matrix from svd components with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, svd

I'm working on SVD using pyspark. But in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html) as well as any other place I didn't find how to reconstruct the matrix back using the segemented vectors.For example, using the svd of pyspark, I got `U`, `s` and `V` matrix as below.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
rows = sc.parallelize([
    Vectors.sparse(5, {1: 1.0, 3: 7.0}),
    Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
])

mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# Compute the top 5 singular values and corresponding singular vectors.
svd = mat.computeSVD(5, computeU=True)
U = svd.U       # The U factor is a RowMatrix.
s = svd.s       # The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
V = svd.V       # The V factor is a local dense matrix.
```

Now, I want to reconstruct back the original matrix by multiplying it back. The equation is:

`mat_cal = U.diag(s).V.T`

In python, we can easily do it. But in pyspark I'm not getting the result.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820956/how-to-reconstruct-original-matrix-from-svd-components-with-spark) link. But it's in scala and I don't know the how to convert it in pyspark. If someone can guide me, it will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `u` [to  diagonal matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48348828/10938362) `Σ`:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseMatrix

Σ = DenseMatrix(len(s), len(s), np.diag(s).ravel("F"))
```

Transpose `V`, [convert to column major](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43641166/10938362) and then convert back to `DenseMatrix`

```py
V_ = DenseMatrix(V.numCols, V.numRows, V.toArray().transpose().ravel("F"))
```

[Multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33558755/10938362):

```py
mat_ = U.multiply(Σ).multiply(V_)
```

Inspect the results:

```py
for row in mat_.rows.take(3): 
    print(row.round(12))
```

```
[0. 1. 0. 7. 0.]
[2. 0. 3. 4. 5.]
[4. 0. 0. 6. 7.]
```

Check [the norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

```
np.linalg.norm(np.array(rows.collect()) - np.array(mat_.rows.collect())
```

```
1.2222842061189339e-14
```

Of course the last two steps are used only for testing, and won't be feasible on real life data.

Comment: I am surprised this works as U is a `RowMatrix` then `mat_ = U.multiply(Σ).multiply(V_) ` will return the following error:

`'RowMatrix' object has no attribute 'collect'`